# H2 HEXTORAW gives chinese char output

Tags: sql, h2, dbunit

I'm trying to write a dbunit test with the H2 database for a query using the HEXTORAW function

```
select hextoraw('79E6AAA933FA493990CC7502B5167D49')
```

gives me

> 秦ꪩ㏺䤹郌甂딖絉

as output on H2, the real oracle database where the code will run gives me

> 79  e6  aa  a9  33  fa  49  39  90  cc  75  02  b5  16  7d  49

Do I need to configure H2 differently so I get the right output ?  This currently blocks my unit testing and I don't see a way out of it.

Comment: any solution?  I'm also seeing this happen when using the hextoraw() in H2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CAST('79E6AAA933FA493990CC7502B5167D49' AS RAW(16)) from dual
```

shoulld work

Comment: Works thanks it's not relevant anymore for me since this project is long behind me, but thanks for figuring it out